# Toshiba L505-S5993 / Code 52 on Display Adapter

Tags: windows-7

Replaced HD and used the recovery disk, I am able to update all drivers except for mobile intel 4 series express chipset family.  Its indicating code 52 and have a triangle with exclamation point, currently the driver version is 8.15.10.1883.  I have upgraded the version and still code 52, any help is appreciated.